# Appkernel can't find my bundle after installing it in composer

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php

I'm trying to install a bundle from a local repo.
the composer.json of this bundle is :

```
{
    "name" : "my/bundle",
    "description" : "My Bundle",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "authors" : [{
        "name" : "Sekai",
        "email" : "admin.admina@gmail.com"
    }],
    "keywords" : [
        "my bundle"
    ],
    "license" : [
        "Proprietary"
    ],
    "require" : {
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "my\\Bundle" : ""
        }
    },
    "target-dir" : "my/Bundle",
    "extra" : {
    "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

the result Hierarchy after installing it :

```
-Vendor
 -my
  -bundle
    -My
     -Bundle
```

And this is how I load it in the Appkernel:

```
...
            new my\Bundle\myBundle(),
...
```

I get the error

```
 Class 'my\Bundle\myBundle' not found
```

AmI doing something wrong in the composer?

Comment: Have you checked namespaces of your bundle? It looks like AppKernel can't find this class by provided namespace.

Comment: the namespace is exactly my\Bundle

Comment: And yet your folder name seems to be 'My' and not 'my'.  Copy/paste issue or is your folder really 'My'.  On linux systems, folder names are case sensitive.

Comment: it's My and this is the problem , I don't know why it becomes "My" .. Debian 7

Comment: in AppKernel when I change my to My, the error is fixed , but then a new problem with the space names emerges ..

Comment: any solution to this?